# Infinity slider previous button logic not working

Tags: jquery, css, infinity

I'm trying to create an infinity slider using jQuery. 
The active slide will be 2/3 of the screen, the upcoming slide will be 1/3. So you already see a preview of the next slide.

The slider that I've build is working. When you click `next` the slider will be animated to the left.

**The trick**

On init I duplicate the first two slides after the last slide. When `slideIndex`, that keeps an eye on the current index, is the number of slides minus 1, it will reset the slider to zero. So you've an infinity slider.

**Problem**

The problem comes when I also want to apply the effect when you're at the first slide and click previously. It should basically do the same, but not reset the slider to zero, but to the end of the slides.

```
var slider = $('.slider');
var slides = slider.find('.slides').children();
var slidesW = slides.width();

root.offset = -Math.abs((root.slideIndex * slides.eq(index).width()));
console.log(root.offset);

// Update active class
slides.removeClass('active');
// slides.eq(index).addClass('active');

// Add class active
TweenMax.to(slides.eq(index), 1, {
    className: 'active', 
    onComplete: function() {

        if (root.slideIndex >= (root.numOfSlides - 2)) {

            slider.find('.slides').addClass('no-transition');

            slides.removeClass('active');
            slides.filter(':first').addClass('active');

            root.offset = 0;

            TweenMax.set(slider.find('.slides'), {
                x: root.offset, 
                onComplete: function() {
                    root.slideIndex = 0;
                    $('#footer .paging #indicator').find('span').html('01');

                    return false;
                }
            });

        } 
    }
});

// Remove no-transition class
slider.find('.slides').removeClass('no-transition');

// Change position of ul.slides
TweenMax.to(slider.find('.slides'), 0.4, {
    x: root.offset
});
```

Because I have an if statement of `if (root.slideIndex === (root.numOfSlides - 2)) {` it will always be resetting to zero, when `slideIndex` is equal to `root.numOfSlides - 2`. So its doesn't matter if you click previous or next, when `slideIndex` is in my example at slide 4, it will reset to zero.

I recreate the slider in a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEmozr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if (dir == "ss-prev") {
    // root.slideIndex--;
    root.slideIndex = (root.slideIndex - 1 < 0) ? root.numOfSlides - 1 : root.slideIndex - 1;
    console.log('prev', root.slideIndex);
}
```

By:

```
if (dir == "ss-prev") {
    // root.slideIndex--;
    root.slideIndex = (root.slideIndex - 1 < 0) ? root.numOfSlides - 3 : root.slideIndex - 1;
    console.log('prev', root.slideIndex);
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXBMZJ?editors=1111